# Mathematica Solve returns empty array for many equations

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, equations

I have this very complicated system of 8 equations with 8 unknowns:

```
Solve[{qx + vx - B Cos[phibr] == L/2, qy + vy - A Cos[phibe] ==L/2, q_x   + v_x + B cos[phi_br] == L/2, qy + vy + A Cos[phibe] == L/2, B w_br Sin[phibr]== v, A wbe Sin[phi_be] == v, -B wbr Sin[phi_br] == v, -A web Sin[phibe] == v}, {qx, vx, qy, vy, A, phibe, B, phibr}]
```

But it always returns {}, an empty array. Is Mathematica simply not built for this many equations?

Comment: Is `_` in `phi_br` intentional? In mathematica '_' has [special meaning](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html), `Blank[]`.

Comment: You have used cos[] in one place and it must be Cos[]. This Simplify[Reduce[{ qx+vx- B Cos[phibr]==L/2, qy+vy- A Cos[phibe]==L/2, qx+vx+B Cos[phibr]==L/2, qy+vy+A Cos[phibe]==L/2, B wbr Sin[phibr]==v, A wbe Sin[phibe]==v, -B wbr Sin[phibr]==v, -A web Sin[phibe]==v}, {qx, vx, qy, vy, A, phibe, B, phibr}]] without the _ finds a solution in a few seconds